# Delegate execution sequence

Tags: c#, delegates

I am learning delegates async and await. I got the idea about delegates that it acts like a function pointer and can very well understand simple delegates. I am also doing some practical on lambda. I would really appreciate if point out the execution flow in this delegate I got hold from one site.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Builder.Filtering.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use(next => context => FilterAsync(context, next));

            app.Run(HelloWorldAsync);
        }

        public async Task FilterAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var body = context.Response.Body;
            var buffer = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = buffer;

            try
            {
                context.Response.Headers["CustomHeader"] = "My Header";

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before\r\n");
                await next(context);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("After\r\n");

                buffer.Position = 0;
                await buffer.CopyToAsync(body);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = body;
            }
        }

        public async Task HelloWorldAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world\r\n");
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                // We set the server by name before default args so that command line arguments can override it.
                // This is used to allow deployers to choose the server for testing.
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

My understanding is, first `FilterAsync` is called, then `HelloWorldAsync` is called. But how does it get to know when to call `HelloWorldAsync`? Also, what is the role of `await next(context);`?

I am not looking for deep understanding of .net core. It is just a sample to understand delegation flow.

Comment: Is it like this-await next(context) calls HelloWorldAsync ?

Comment: If you are not looking for understanding of .net core - that's not the best example, because how it works is quite related to how .net core works.

Comment: Thanks,i actually have some understanding of Core .I added that comment so that answer is basically relted to flow and not .net core terminology .Next time wil be more specific.Thanks for the comment